# Does anyone know how to select parts of test methods in a test case run in a test suite?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

For example, a test case named ExampleTest

```
ExampleTest {
    testA{};
    testB{};
    testC();
}
```

I could run all this class with `TestSuite.addTestSuite(ExampleTest.class);`

but, how to select `testA` and `testB` run into `TestSuite`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368915/exclude-individual-junit-test-methods-without-modifying-the-test-class

Comment: Can't you just mark testc to be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Ideas:

- See if it makes sense to split **ExampleTest into 2 test classes** based on your partition
- Otherwise **use Categories to tag your tests** and then **run tests which belong to a specific category**. Its simpler in NUnit, JUnit seems to require you to create an empty/ marker interface to get this done. [A sample link with code](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0).

Comment: +1 for categories, but it looks as if question is for JUnit 3