# selenium run only few methods

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I know by creating test suite I can run all my class files, using code like

```
suite.addTestSuite( TestCase3.class);  
suite.addTestSuite( TestCase2.class);
suite.addTestSuite( TestCase1.class);
```

But what if I dont want to run all the methods in a class file? I want to run only specific test methods inside a test class, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Below links might be useful for you

[Exclude individual JUnit Test methods without modifying the Test class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368915/exclude-individual-junit-test-methods-without-modifying-the-test-class)

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the execution across classes I highly recommend [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html)!

It's well documented and offers a whole lot of useful and easy to use functionality for custom made test executions.

For your requirement, TestNG Groups will do the job.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(groups = {"groupA"})
public class ATest{

    @Test(groups = {"group1"})
    public void testA1() {

    }

    @Test(groups = {"group2"})
    public void testA2() {

    }

}
```

&

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(groups = {"groupB"})
public class BTest{

    @Test(groups = {"group1"})
    public void testB1() {

    }

    @Test(groups = {"group2"})
    public void testB2() {

    }

}
```

I guess you already know which methods will run if you start "group1" methods right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to further build your suite.
something like :

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("TmpTest1");
    test.setVerbose(3);
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    XmlClass cl = new XmlClass();
    cl.setName("my.pkg.Tests");
    XmlInclude incMet = new XmlInclude("testSimpleTrue");
    List<XmlInclude> incMetList = new ArrayList<XmlInclude>();
    incMetList.add(incMet);
    cl.setIncludedMethods(incMetList);
    classes.add(cl);

    test.setXmlClasses(classes);

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);

    testng.setXmlSuites(suites);
```